# Eclipse JUNO not starting

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I tried to start Eclipse, it just shows loading eclipse and then stops/crashes after a while, I haven't changed anything from before.

even I tried to replace it with other version but some thing happens, when I open it with terminal I get this error:

> -- ERROR: RebelPlugin.getDefault() retured null!! Likely cause: plugin not started properly!
>   logout
>
> [Process completed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the RebelPlugin is causing issues. The simplest option is to install a new Eclipse and run that instead. You can reuse your previous workspace and the code will be untouched, so you will just loose some time.

There are other alternatives to try, but they may be a bit more advanced. From commandline you can try to uninstall the RebelPlugin and see if that makes a difference, and then reinstalling.

```
java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_<version>.jar
-application org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate
-command uninstall
-featureId <feature_id of rebelplugin>
-version <version>
```

[See the Eclipse manual for more information](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_standalone.html)